# Como inserir uma quebra de linha dentro do echo no shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Queria saber se existe alguma forma de inserir uma quebra de linha dentro do `echo` do shell script.

Por exemplo, no comando:

```
echo "Bom dia fulano"
```

gostaria que a saída fosse:

```
Bom dia
fulano
```

Sei que dá pra fazer assim:

```
echo "bom dia"
echo "fulano"
```

Mas gostaria mesmo de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer isso com um `echo` só.

Comment: Existem várias outras opções além do `-e`. Dê uma olhada neste pequeno curso: http://rberaldo.com.br/curso-shell-script-comandos-basicos-linux/#cmd_echo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Experimente

```
echo -e "Bom dia\nfulano"
```

A opção [`e`](http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html) faz com que o carácter de *newline* seja interpretado.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada!!!

Comment: Existem várias outras opções além do `-e`. Dê uma olhada neste pequeno curso: http://rberaldo.com.br/curso-shell-script-comandos-basicos-linux/#cmd_echo

Comment: @Beraldo outras opções para a quebra de linha? E que na sua pagina so vejo `printf(...)` como candidato a substituir o `echo -e`

Comment: Tem também a expansão do $"Bomdia\nMundo" e do $'Bomdia\nMundo', isso sem precisar nem pedir ao `echo` interpretar escapes; Essas expansões são da própria Shell e indicam para interpretar os escapes dentro das aspas

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar em `printf` que resulta bem:

```
printf "Ola\nMundo\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira também:

```
echo $'Bom dia\nfulano'
```

Como esta expansão é feita pelo `bash` e não pelo comando `echo`, o argumento `$'Bom dia\nfulano'` funciona com qualquer comando, e não só com o `echo` ou o `printf`. Exemplo:

```
$ figlet $'Bom dia\nfulano'
 ____                        _ _       
| __ )  ___  _ __ ___     __| (_) __ _ 
|  _ \ / _ \| '_ ` _ \   / _` | |/ _` |
| |_) | (_) | | | | | | | (_| | | (_| |
|____/ \___/|_| |_| |_|  \__,_|_|\__,_|

  __       _                   
 / _|_   _| | __ _ _ __   ___  
| |_| | | | |/ _` | '_ \ / _ \ 
|  _| |_| | | (_| | | | | (_) |
|_|  \__,_|_|\__,_|_| |_|\___/
```

Answer (score -1):

este formato também funciona:

```
echo "
Bom dia

Fulano!"
```